# Variable font not adjusting with mousemove event listener

Tags: javascript, css, dom, fonts

I am trying to have my variable font adjust based on the clientX position of the mouse. However I'm having trouble getting the font to be responsive.

Here is my code:

```
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  text.style.fontVariationSettings = `'wght' 100, 'wdth' ${e.clientX.value}`;
});
```

If I console.log `text.style`, all fields are simply `""`.

Comment: "e.clientX.value" there is no property value in `e.clientX` actually `e.clientX` is just a number, and `fontVariationSettings` works with `@font-face` rule and not the way you are doing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-variation-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.clientX.value` is undefined, thus:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  text.style.fontVariationSettings = `'wght' 100, 'wdth' ${e.clientX}`;
});
```

```html
<div class="text">Hello World</div>
```